# Спрашивать ЗА улицу, район

Tags: управление, предлоги

Недавно услышала такое выражение "Ты меня не спрашивала за улицу, ты спрашивала за район". Речь шла о месте проживания человека, т. е. в каком районе и на какой улице он живет. В процессе разговора девушка подумала, что парень сказал название улицы, где живет. А он говорил о районе, произошла путаница, и в итоге мной была услышана эта фраза. Правильно ли так говорить? Или все же правильно сказать "про улицу, а не про район"?

Comment: По мне, так лучше сто раз "спросить за улицу, за что угодно", чем один раз употребить такой пассив, как у Вас :(( (мной была услышана...).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Общелитературный русский язык требует в подобных случаях употребления конструкции *"Спрашивать о чем-то"* или *"Спрашивать про что-то"*: ***Спрашивать о районе, улице*** или ***Спрашивать про район, улицу*** - эти варианты сейчас равноправны, хотя второй, украинско-южорусский, видимо, постепенно вытесняет первый, исторический.

Вариант "спрашивать за что-то (улицу, район)" фиксируется в основном у носителей т. н. "одесского диалекта" - реально никогда не существовавшего и используемого в основном в иронических образованиях. Иногда некоторые носители воспринимают конструкцию "за что-то" как реально возможную - и начинают повторять уже без стилистической окраски. Но скорее всего услышанное вами - это ирония, хотя и становится уже избитой.

Comment: Да, одесский. А разве "за" в смысле "про" носители этого диалекта никогда всерьёз не говорят, только в шутку? Думал, что не только...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Не думаю, что они не понимают противоречия с литературным языком. Кстати, а вы вообще видели одессита, говорящего серьезно? Я встречал выдающих себя за таковых - и пытающихся что-то говорить серьезно и без своих любимых хохмочек. Жалкое зрелище. ))))

Comment: Верю, верю!)) Я их немного вживую видел (да может вообще ни одного :( ), в Одессе ни разу не был, но хотел бы побывать. И вообще мне это очень интересно, нравится, я уверен, что вы всё правильно пишете, и мне очень нравится ваш комментарий!))) Сужу, видимо, только по тому, что видел на экране, ну и интуитивно что-то предполагаю.

Answer (score 2):

**Это не стандартный русский.**

Использование "за" вместо "по", "о" или "про" чаще всего наблюдается у украинских носителей русского языка. И данную конструкцию они "принесли" в русский из украинского языка.
Например, от украинцев очень часто можно услышать фразу "Я за ...(тобой/ним/ней/ними) скучаю", хотя согласно нормам русского языка конечно же правильно говорить "по тебе/ней/нему/ним".

Касаемо вашего примера - **правильно говорить "спрашивать про улицу/район" или "об улице/ о районе**)